# How to save a csv file into a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a window application in asp.net using C#. I want to browse and import .csv file and save it in the database. Importing part I have done. Now, how am i supposed to save it in the database ? I am new to the language so please help

Comment: in which control your are imported?

Comment: Save the Datagrid values.....other wise you can check this one [Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1695615.aspx/1)

Comment: Create a table and insert the values. There are plenty of [CSV-readers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) that help you to get them.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: This question is very incomplete. What data, what database, fixed schema or not, ...

Comment: yeah thats what i dont know how do i save the values. Can you write down the code here ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman right now i need to use fixed schema....will try dynamic schema later..

Comment: @CuongLe well i imported the data into gridview u see....dont have time to "try". i just need the damn solution coz my boss want it today

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADO.NET, you will need to look up Data Adapters and the like.

If your Importing the Spreadsheet into a DataTable or DataSet you can use a Data Adapter to populate a table in the Database using an INSERT command.

Look up http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.aspx

Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a file upload mechanism in place, (for example, using the FileUpload control), just iterate through the lines in the CSV file on the server, parse them into fields using an existing CSV reader (don't try to code your own unless your data is completely trivial, you won't handle all of the edge cases), and just execute a bunch of SQL INSERT statements against your database using your calling convention of choice.